# Typeorm find methods returns wrong timestamp time

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

So, I'm using express + typeorm + postgresql and when I save an entity in DB the timestamp columns gets the correct UTC Date, however, when I fetch data from DB, every timestamp returned comes with 3 more hours added to it. What is going on? Why are retrived dates not exactly the same as they are in DB? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a diff between the timezone of the DB and the server.
To normalize this you can set both to 'UTC' timezone and work with that.

PostgreSQL's timezone:

```sql
// get
show timezone;

// set
SET TIMEZONE='UTC';
```

Server's timezone:

```js
// get
console.log(process.env.TZ)

// set
process.env.TZ = 'UTC'
```

Another solution is to use `typeorm`'s `@Column` decorator API for the [transformer](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-options) methods on the data returned from the DB. This method will get as input the data from the DB and will return it transformed.

```
@Column({
    transformer: { 
        from(value: DatabaseType): EntityType,
        to(value: EntityType): DatabaseType 
    }
})
someDate: Date;
```